# UPDATE query in phpmyadmin keeps failing

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql-update, substring

I am trying to update a column with a substring from a second column:

UPDATE `tb01_content` SET `fulltext` = (SELECT SUBSTRING(`introtext`,INSTR(`introtext`, 'virtuemart_product_id')+22,3)) WHERE catid = 41 or catid = 45 or catid = 46 or catid = 47;

I have tested the SELECT SUBSTRING with hardcoded strings and it extracts the right information. The query above returns with 0 rows affected. Guess it is an issue with the phpmyadmin ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you typing the UPDATE query in the SQL box, or using the Edit link/double clicking a field to update directly from the graphical interface? Also, which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Hi, the issue is solved. The query actually worked, however the substring was only found in a single record. I had not expected that.